# Image in button - j2me

Tags: button, java-me, icons, midp, lcdui

I am trying to build a simple menu-based GUI with J2ME. The menu entries are currently objects of classes derived from the class Button. Is there any way I can:

1. Replace the text in the button and have an image show instead, sort of an icon?
2. Make the text and image appear side by side on the same menu bar.

If my question is not clear, please let me know and I will edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own `Item` that looks like a button by extending the [`CustomItem` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html).

This is a working MIDlet with a good `MyButton` class:

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Item;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemStateListener;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

public class TestMidlet extends MIDlet implements ItemStateListener {
    class MyButton extends CustomItem {
        private Image _image = null;
        private boolean _down = false;
        private int _clicks = 0;

        public MyButton(Image image) {
            super("");
            _image = image;
        }

        // Button's image
        public void setImage(Image image) {
            _image = image;
            repaint();
        }
        public Image getImage() {
            return _image;
        }

        // Has the button been clicked?
        public boolean isClicked() {
            if(_clicks>0) {
                _clicks -= 1;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Is the button currently down?
        public boolean isDown() {
            return _down;
        }
        public void setDown(boolean down) {
            if(_down)
                _clicks += 1;
            if(down!=_down) {
                _down = down;
                repaint();
                notifyStateChanged();
            }
        }
        public void setDown() {
            setDown(true);
        }
        public void setUp() {
            setDown(false);
        }

        // Minimal button size = image size
        protected int getMinContentHeight() {
            return getImage().getHeight();
        }
        protected int getMinContentWidth() {
            return getImage().getWidth();
        }
        // Preferred button size = image size + borders
        protected int getPrefContentHeight(int width) {
            return getImage().getHeight()+2;
        }
        protected int getPrefContentWidth(int height) {
            return getImage().getWidth()+2;
        }

        // Button painting procedure
        protected void paint(Graphics g, int w, int h) {
            // Fill the button with grey color - background 
            g.setColor(192, 192, 192);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            // Draw the image in the center of the button
            g.drawImage(getImage(), w/2, h/2, Graphics.HCENTER|Graphics.VCENTER);
            // Draw the borders
            g.setColor(isDown()?0x000000:0xffffff);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, w, 0);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, h);
            g.setColor(isDown()?0xffffff:0x000000);
            g.drawLine(0, h-1, w, h-1);
            g.drawLine(w-1, 0, w-1, h);
        }

        // If FIRE key is pressed, the button becomes pressed (down state)
        protected void keyPressed(int c) {
            if(getGameAction(c)==Canvas.FIRE)
                setDown();
        }
        // When FIRE key is released, the button becomes released (up state)
        protected void keyReleased(int c) {
            if(getGameAction(c)==Canvas.FIRE)
                setUp();
        }
        // The same for touchscreens
        protected void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
            setDown();
        }
        protected void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
            setUp();
        }
    }

    MyButton button = null;

    public void itemStateChanged(Item item) {
        if(item==button) {
            if(button.isClicked())
                System.out.print("clicked, ");
            System.out.println(button.isDown()?"currently down":"currently up");
        }
    }

    public void startApp() {
        try {
            Form form = new Form("Example");
            button = new MyButton(Image.createImage("/icon.png"));
            form.append(button);
            form.setItemStateListener(this);
            Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(form);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi BlaXpirit! thanks for the reply. I looked CustomItem up. On further thought, here is some additional info.: i already have a class called VoiceButton which extends Button and implments some more features. So what I want to do is to have some sort of a container class, one that can have a VoiceButton object and also an image associated with it. Will CustomItem do the trick?

Comment: I wouln't recommend extending the Button class at all. I'll edit my answer and add some example.

Comment: If you need text AND image in one button, write here, and I'll try to make it. But better do it by yourself!

Comment: il try to use this code and fit to more of what I need (if it is not done so already). thanks!

Comment: Hey BlaXpirit! Thanks for the reply. I managed to add the text functionality to the button. Many thanks! Answer accepted!