# How should I handle the key events in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

How should I handle the key events for `CustomItem` in J2ME?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/Key-Event.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. We should override the method "protected void keyPressed(int key)" of CustomItem in the derived class of CustomItem.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the complete example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/Canvasforprocessingkeycodeandcommands.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says.

[Example of CustomItem usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218852/image-in-button-j2me/3246218#3246218)