# TextEdit/TextBox onKey events in J2me

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

I'm developing (or trying to) a J2ME application. I need to be able to handle onKeyEvents (keyDown/keyPressed/keyUp...) in TextEdit/TextBoxes, but I've learned that such thing is not possible in J2me, at least not in a simple way as in Java/Android development (myEdit.setOnKeyListener() for example). I've read something about using Canvas, but I'm not sure how can I use that to make it work for me.

Answer to this question ( [Image in button - j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218852/image-in-button-j2me) ) involves using the CustomItem class and make an item look/act like a Button. Is there anyway to use the same approach?

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` and `TextField` objects are high-level GUI stuff, available when doing `javax.microedition.lcdui.Form` stuff.

In order to use `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` you must use `javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas` (low-level GUI stuff).

But what you're probably really after, is LWUIT (https://lwuit.java.net). It is a framework built on `javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas` which gives you a Form-like API with all the things `javax.microedition.lcdui.Form` is missing.